# php-Fetch redirect URL from Google

Tags: php, google-search

This is a search URL generated by google:

`https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=http://EXAMPLE.com/example-Article/&ct=ga&cd=CAIyHjliOWMxZGQ0MzEzZDc1MWY6Y28uaW46ZW46R0I6Ug&usg=AFQjCNGoEabdV1jKNPGH8vNeiuoec_E2Iw`

Now it contains a redirect URL.

`http://EXAMPLE.com/example-Article/`

How do I extract this URL from the above using PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this eventually. I used the `parse_url` and the `parse_str` functions:

```
$baseURL = "https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=http://www.EXAMPLE.com/MY-ARTICLE-&ct=ga&cd=CAIyHjZkZjRjNDk2NTAwYWE1ZGU6Y28uaW46ZW46SU46Ug&usg=AFQjCNGT48irR-R0yx_PiiDqOHYW14bc1w"

$URLParse = parse_url($baseURL);

parse_str($URLParse['query'],$queryResult);

echo $queryResult['url'];
```